# How do you insert a newline in message body of mule logger component

Tags: logging, mule, mule-studio

Can anyone tell me how to insert a new line in the message of a mule logger component?

For example, I have the following in the message for the logger:

```
Payload is: #[payload] 
Inbound Headers:  #[headers:INBOUND:*] 
Outbound Headers:  #[headers:OUTBOUND:*]  
Exceptions:  #[exception]
```

I'd like to insert a new line after each of the above.  I've tried just adding \n to the end of each line, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use MEL:

```
    <logger
        message="#['Payload is:'+payload+'\nInbound Headers: '+message.inboundProperties.entrySet()+'\nOutbound Headers: '+message.outboundProperties.entrySet()+'\nExceptions: '+exception]"
        level="INFO" />
```

Comment: It would still be better to use System.getProperty('line.separator') instead of \n to make it closs-platform.

Comment: @Seba Sounds good, but first we would need to make sure that `\n` isn't already interpreted by MVEL as `System.getProperty('line.separator')`.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
Payload is: #[payload] #[System.getProperty('line.separator')] Inbound Headers: ...
```

Answer (score 2):

use expression-transformer:

```
<expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload = message.payload + System.getProperty('line.separator')]" doc:name="Append CRLF"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1) Use:
 #[System.getProperty('line.separator')]

2) Use:
 #['\n'] eg:   #['Hello\n'+payload+'Welcome to \n new line']

Answer (score 1):

we can you the below format

```
#['\n'] #['\n']  #['\n'] #['\n']  #[payload] #[System.getProperty('line.separator')]
```

Comment: #['\n'] is best and simplest option of all - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

//This should work. tested in mule 3.9 CE

```
<logger message="Payload is #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]  #[System.lineSeparator()]  INBOUND HEADERS =  #[headers:inbound:*]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax with Mule 4:

My Input payload: #["\n"] #[payload]

Answer (score -1):

Try this in literal mode.
#["\n"] #[ payload]

Comment: Isn't it the same as in [Lova's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52163595/2227743)?