# How do I add a line break / blank line after my LOG statement?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, line-breaks

I want to add a blank line after my `LOG` statement in order to make my logs more *separated* and *readable*.

How do I do this?

**Current statement:**

```
 LOGGER.info("Person's name is  {} .", person.getName());
```

Note that I don't want to do this after *every* statement, just for certain statements.

Comment: **<B>Add #\n instead of \n</B>** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254304/how-do-you-insert-a-newline-in-message-body-of-mule-logger-component

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Simply add `\n` at the end of the string to log.

```java
LOGGER.info("Person's name is  {} .\n", person.getName());
```

If you are in a windows environment use `\r\n`

---

**OS independet solution:**

To get the right value of new line if you don't know the end operating system of your application, you can use `System.lineSeperator()` or with < JDK 7 `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

```java
LOGGER.info("Person's name is  {} .{}", person.getName(), System.lineSeparator());
```

Comment: Use System.lineSeparator() as mentioned by lordkain

Answer (score 37):

dont use `\n` character, but ask the System what is the newline propery. could be different in linuxor windows or..

so use

```
System.lineSeparator();
```

or before java 7 use

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```